# PHP's JavaScript Modal

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

I'm having a problem with my java script. The Modal works fine at first but whenever I click it on its second time there are 2 modals that appear, the previous and the new ones. it stacks every time I click the button.

Comment: Where you call `ModalCustom`?

Comment: Post Updated, added the PHP that calls the modal

Comment: Try to change `$("#something").find(".modal");` to `$(el).find(".modal");` and make sure what the `console.log($el.lenght)` return everytime you click.

Comment: it still open 2 modals

Comment: Please add `$(el).find(".modal");` before the condition `if ($el.lenght){` and when youo click check the output in the browser console. Or also add alerts inside `if/else` statement to make sure where the condition lead.

Comment: it says $el.lenght is undefined.

Comment: That mean the `.modal` not found inside the `#something`. try also `console.log( $("#something").find(".modal").length );`

Comment: the value is 0.

Comment: I added a script in else $el.lenght = 1; and it now has a value of 1. But el.replaceWith(div.children[0]); clears the screen, it should have replaced the modal.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

```
function appendHtml(el, str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;
    $el = el;
    $(el).find(".modal");

    if ($el.lenght){
        var cnt = $(div.children[0]);
        $(".modal").replaceWith(cnt);
    } else {
        el.appendChild(div.children[0]);
        $el.lenght = 1;
    }
}
```